# Запятая после конструкции, заключённой между двумя тире

Tags: пунктуация

*По тарелкам были разложены дары моря — кальмар, скумбрия, красный осётр — а также некоторые фрукты сомнительной свежести.*

Здесь перед "а также" нужна запятая. Но я не уверен, где её ставить. Сразу после "осётр"? После второго тире?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, за "после второго тире" вообще-то убивают канделябром.

А вот перед ним, аккурат за осетром, самое ей, запятой, место.

***По тарелкам были разложены дары моря — кальмар, скумбрия, красный осётр, — а также некоторые фрукты сомнительной свежести.***